# Ajax post not incrementing index values in Firebase DB

Tags: json, ajax, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am using an ajax post to add new array information to an already existing json object i have in Firebase, the post is all working fine but it does not increment the index value, it just uses a random set of characters from what i can see.

Why is it doing this and how can i change it to follow on from the previous index value?

My post code...

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "blahblahblah.json",
  data: JSON.stringify({
      FIELD2: $('#title').val(),
      FIELD3: $('#author').val(),
  }),
  error: function(e) {
    console.log('%c Epic Fail', 'color: #fff; font-weight: bold;background:red;padding:20px;');
  },
  success: function(data){   // A function to be called if request succeeds
    console.log('%c Hazaaaa', 'color: #fff; font-weight: bold;background:lime;padding:20px;');
  },
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

And this is how my json looks after an update of new information.

```
84:{FIELD1: "6656640", FIELD10: "The Folio Society", FIELD11: "Hardcover", FIELD12: "304", FIELD13: "2005", …}
85:{FIELD1: "168668", FIELD10: "Simon & Schuster ", FIELD11: "Paperback", FIELD12: "453", FIELD13: "2004", …}
86:{FIELD1: "100915", FIELD10: "HarperCollins Publishers", FIELD11: "Paperback", FIELD12: "206", FIELD13: "2005", …}
-LBaSxkTucRyHqfqEdDI:{FIELD2: "TEST TITLE", FIELD3: "TEST AUTHOR"}
-LBaXDRfe3tjZEBoJwHy:{FIELD2: "dave", FIELD3: "smith"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Database recommends against using sequential numbers for indexing. To read more about why that is, see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

When you send a `POST` verb to the Firebase Database REST API, it creates a new child node with a so-called push ID as the key. Those are the values like `-LBaSxkTucRyHqfqEdDI` that you see.

There is no support built in to the Firebase Database for generating sequential numeric indexes. If you insist on using them, you will have to roll your own. This means you'll have two options:

1. Read the entire array in the client, find the next index, and then write it back. You'll want to do this in a transaction, to ensure users are not overwriting each other's changes.
2. Keep track of the highest index you've handed out in a separate field. Then read that field in the client, find the next index, and write it back. You'll also want to do this in a transaction, but the transaction only needs to apply to the count.

If this sounds complex and more involved than you'd like: that is one of the many reasons why Firebase recommends against using numeric sequential indexes, and doesn't have the operation built in.